# Flat File Source returned status value 2 and status text The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssis, etl

en la base de datos destino tengo un campo decimal(15,2) y en el origen de la etl el campo esta en un archivo csv, automaticamente ssis me lo reconoce como tipo de dato DT_STR lo que hice fue cambiarlo a DT_NUMERIC 18 0 en el editor avanzado. pero cuando ejecuto me saca el error mencionado en el titulo de esta pregunta.

tambien intente lo siguiente:

1. realizar la conversion con una tarea de conversion de datos
2. realizar la conversion con una tarea de lolumna derivada con la siguiente expresion:
   ISNULL([CAMPO_VALOR]) ? "0" : FINDSTRING([CAMPO_VALOR],".",1) > 1 ? REPLACE(REPLACE([CAMPO_VALOR],".",""),",",".") : [CAMPO_VALOR]
3. Intente reconstruir el archivo por medio de componente de script

Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Que has intentado?, pon un ejemplo mínimo verificable que hayas intentado para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte, aquí las preguntas que no muestran algún intento no son bien recibidas y terminan por ser cerradas, edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que sea necesario para entender tu problema, date una vuelta por el [Recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y en [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: gracias por responder antonio, tambien probe configurando en el editor avanzado DT_NUMERIC 15 2 en el external y en la salida, sin embargo sigue el mismo error. Lo habia dejado con 18 0 para aumentar el tamaño para evitar la posible perdida de datos, pero sigo sin solucionar

Answer (score 0):

logre solucionarlo, creando una tarea de script antes de la tarea de flujo de datos. me di cuenta que cada registro finalizaba con un punto y coma. Entonces dentro de la tarea de script le quite el punto y coma de la siguiente manera:

```
public void Main()
        {
            string FilePath = Dts.Variables["User::VarFilePath"].Value.ToString();
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);
         
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(FilePath);

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                file.WriteLine(line.TrimEnd(';'));
            }

            file.Close();

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```